# isc-dhcp-server install and run problem

Tags: networking, apt, dhcp

Im trying to set up my pi as an access point with the instructions from [Adafruit](http://learn.adafruit.com/setting-up-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-wifi-access-point/install-software). However, for some reason, `sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server` always fails. I have looked at [this link](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=34503), but there is a subnet defined in my dhcpd.conf (from Adafruit):

/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

```
              .
              .
              .
#    range 10.0.29.10 10.0.29.230;
#  }
#}

subnet 192.168.42.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.42.10 192.168.42.50;
option broadcast-address 192.168.42.255;
option routers 192.168.42.1;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
option domain-name "local";
option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
}
```

When I do `sudo apt-get install isc-dhcp-server`, i get:

```
Generating /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server...
[FAIL] Starting ISC DHCP server: dhcpd[....] check syslog for diagnostics. ... failed!
 failed!
```

and

```
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo sh -c "echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward"
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED \
> -j ACCEPT
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo sh -c "iptables-save > /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat"
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo service hostapd start
[ ok ] Starting advanced IEEE 802.11 management: hostapd.
pi@raspberrypi ~ $ sudo service isc-dhcp-server start
[FAIL] Starting ISC DHCP server: dhcpd[....] check syslog for diagnostics. ... failed!
 failed!
```

/var/log/syslog:

```
Jul 26 03:05:25 raspberrypi dhcpd: Wrote 0 leases to leases file.
Jul 26 03:05:25 raspberrypi dhcpd:
Jul 26 03:05:25 raspberrypi dhcpd: No subnet declaration for wlan0 (192.168.42.\
1).
Jul 26 03:05:25 raspberrypi dhcpd: ** Ignoring requests on wlan0.  If this is n\
ot what
Jul 26 03:05:25 raspberrypi dhcpd:    you want, please write a subnet declarati\
on
Jul 26 03:05:25 raspberrypi dhcpd:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network s\
egment
Jul 26 03:05:25 raspberrypi dhcpd:    to which interface wlan0 is attached. **
Jul 26 03:05:25 raspberrypi dhcpd:
Jul 26 03:05:25 raspberrypi dhcpd:
Jul 26 03:05:25 raspberrypi dhcpd: Not configured to listen on any interfaces!
```

How do i fix this?

Comment: I still have the problem on latest up-to-date Raspbian. It seems to be related to this bug:
https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=590641 It doesn't seem like it's been fixed yet, and it probably also affect Raspbian

Answer (score 11, accepted):

if you are sure that subnet set in dhpcd config belongs to already configured interface (I'm guessing, wlan0). Compare IP subnets in /etc/network/interfaces and /etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf .

Also, on Debian (and thus Raspbian), check /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server, as it should contain name of your interface, like this:

```
# Defaults for dhcp initscript
# sourced by /etc/init.d/dhcp
# installed at /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server by the maintainer scripts

#
# This is a POSIX shell fragment
#

# On what interfaces should the DHCP server (dhcpd) serve DHCP requests?
#   Separate multiple interfaces with spaces, e.g. "eth0 eth1".
INTERFACES="wlan0"
```

both things were set in the tutorial, so I'm assuming you omit at least one of them.

Comment: I checked everything, and everything seemed correct, but something worked

Comment: this is wrong! You need to have `INTERFACES=""` in defaults as it shipped! All you need is to define ALL the /etc/network/interfaces subnets by a `subnet {}` clause. For the subnets you do not need to be served by DHCPD you need an empty `subnet` clause. Putting interface name in INTERFACES, as suggested here, breaks DHCPD. Verified on Raspbian Jessie.

Answer (score 5):

You need to have INTERFACES="" in defaults as it shipped! Even more - automatic update can overwrite it btw. This issue is DHCPD-dependent, not an OS-dependent. All you need is to define ALL the /etc/network/interfaces subnets by a subnet {} clause. For the subnets you do not need to be served by DHCPD you need an empty subnet clause like this :

```
# No service will be given on this subnet, but declaring it helps the
# DHCP server to understand the network topology.

subnet 192.168.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
}
```

the comment above is from the *original config sample shipped*. In my case on this network it was no need to serve any IP requests, but without this **empty** `subnet` clause DHCPD refused to start like this :

```
Jan 29 19:08:44 pi dhcpd: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.3.1
Jan 29 19:08:44 pi dhcpd: Copyright 2004-2014 Internet Systems Consortium.
Jan 29 19:08:44 pi dhcpd: All rights reserved.
Jan 29 19:08:44 pi dhcpd: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Jan 29 19:08:44 pi dhcpd: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Server 4.3.1
Jan 29 19:08:44 pi dhcpd: Copyright 2004-2014 Internet Systems Consortium.
Jan 29 19:08:44 pi dhcpd: All rights reserved.
Jan 29 19:08:44 pi dhcpd: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
 Jan 29 19:08:44 pi dhcpd: Wrote 2 leases to leases file.
 Jan 29 19:08:44 pi dhcpd:
 Jan 29 19:08:44 pi dhcpd: No subnet declaration for wlan0 (no IPv4 addresses).
 Jan 29 19:08:44 pi dhcpd: ** Ignoring requests on wlan0.  If this is not what
 Jan 29 19:08:44 pi dhcpd:    you want, please write a subnet declaration
 Jan 29 19:08:44 pi dhcpd:    in your dhcpd.conf file for the network segment
 Jan 29 19:08:44 pi dhcpd:    to which interface wlan0 is attached. **
 Jan 29 19:08:44 pi dhcpd:
 Jan 29 19:08:44 pi dhcpd:
 Jan 29 19:08:44 pi dhcpd: Not configured to listen on any interfaces!
 Jan 29 19:08:44 pi dhcpd:
 Jan 29 19:08:44 pi dhcpd: If you think you have received this message due to a bug rather
 Jan 29 19:08:44 pi dhcpd: than a configuration issue please read the section on submitting
 Jan 29 19:08:44 pi dhcpd: bugs on either our web page at www.isc.org or in the README file
 Jan 29 19:08:44 pi dhcpd: before submitting a bug.  These pages explain the proper
 Jan 29 19:08:44 pi dhcpd: process and the information we find helpful for debugging..
 Jan 29 19:08:44 pi dhcpd:
 Jan 29 19:08:44 pi dhcpd: exiting.
 Jan 29 19:08:46 pi isc-dhcp-server[3332]: Starting ISC DHCP server: dhcpdcheck syslog for diagnostics. ... failed!
 Jan 29 19:08:46 pi isc-dhcp-server[3332]: failed!
 Jan 29 19:08:46 pi systemd[1]: isc-dhcp-server.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
 Jan 29 19:08:46 pi systemd[1]: Unit isc-dhcp-server.service entered failed state.
```

The **hell-weird** thing about all this error message is that `/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf` actually *had* a full-featured subnet clause for wlan0's subnet. Adding an *empty* clause for eth0 subnet fixed all the things up.

Putting interface name in INTERFACES, as suggested here, breaks DHCPD. Verified on Raspbian Jessie, and on other OS'es.

Comment: I am not sure that it is the best idea to start one's answer with *This is wrong*, people might think that it is wrong...

Comment: @Ghanima thanks! I've copied my comment to a wrong answer =) missed it =) Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

ISC DHCP server is OK.

change /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server
INTERFACES="wlan0" to eth0

service isc-dhcp-server start
OK?

change /etc/default/isc-dhcp-server
INTERFACES="eth0" to wlan0

......
interface wlan0 does IP address

ifconfig   ,  wlan0 IP?

..
nano /etc/network/interfaces

iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.42.2
netmask 255.255.255.0
..

ifdown wlan0 
ifup wlan0
ifconfig wlan0

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:00:xx:xx:xx:xx
          inet addr:192.168.42.2  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1153 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1178 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:219204 (214.0 KiB)  TX bytes:245615 (239.8 KiB)

service isc-dhcp-server start

Comment: your answer reads a bit cryptic, please, add more explanation next time?

Answer (score 1):

Had exactly the same problem and found the answer in this short tutorial:
http://sirlagz.net/2013/02/10/how-to-use-the-raspberry-pi-as-a-wireless-access-pointrouter-part-3b/

Hope it works for you too!

Barney

Comment: Hi Barney, welcome to Raspberry Pi SE :) usually answers are better if they summarise the pages that they link off to. This means that if the link moves the answer is still useful.

Answer (score -1):

Common mistake when I config/edit headless servers is to use Windows IDE to edit the files. If you do so, use ***Notepad++***, then don't forget to check the ***Format*** is => ***UNIX format*** && ***Encode in UTF-8 without BOM***

Solves most of the weird behavior like this one.